# Configuring siteminder in AEM6

Tags: single-sign-on, aem, siteminder

I want to implement CA siteminder in AEM 6 on publisher. The way it is going to work is that the end user of the application will use a login form and enter into the application. On successful application the user will land on a homepage where she will be able to see her personal information like name, date of birth, medical history and all sort of data. On providing wrong password the user will get an error message. It's like any normal web application. The problem here is that all the user information will be coming from the back end i.e. web services. No user or minimal information will be saved in CRX. I have done some reading on siteminder and found out that some configurations will have to be done on Apache that checks for request. If it's /secure/ the request is redirected to siteminder which upon successful validation redirects to the /homepage.html and passes a number of HTTP headers like userrole. Additionally a cookie SMRESPONSECODE will also be passed. For userrole 'employee' the value of SMRESPONSECODE is 0 and for userrole employer the SMRESPONSECODE is 4. In case of failure, it redirects back to login page with SMRESPONSECODE value being 1 or 2 or 3 depending upon the reason of failure ranging from no user found to wrong password. Also, when SMRESPONSECODE is 3, SITEMINDER will pass some more cookies(to the login page).

I have also gone through this page https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/configuring/single-sign-on.html and found out that Adobe Granite SSO Authentication Handler will have to be configured. But I am still not sure what all header names/cookies I need to configure. Also, I would like to know what all configurations I need to do.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you implemented this? Appreciate your help with the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use SAML authentication. I believe that Siteminder supports SAML. Any specific reason why you want to achieve SSO through ad-hoc ways like cookies, etc.

Configuring SAML based authentication at AEM - http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/security/saml-2-0-authenticationhandler.html